# Prevent page scrolling when mouse is over one particular div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My question is similiar to this [How to prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600454/how-to-prevent-page-scrolling-when-scrolling-a-div-element) but I'm wondering if there is an approach with css and/or react that does not require jQuery.

I want to disable page scrolling on a mouseWheel event when the cursor is over one particular div. 
The div is a graph which zooms on a mouseWheel event, and is rendered by a React component.

I've tried e.preventDefault however chrome tells me

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Found a simple solution for anyone looking.

```
changeScroll(){ 
    let style = document.body.style.overflow 
    document.body.style.overflow = (style === 'hidden') ? 'auto':'hidden'
} 

<div 
    onMouseEnter={this.changeScroll} 
    onMouseLeave={this.changeScroll} /> 
    <ReactComponent/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily + a mouseEnter / mouseLeave event to the <WhateverComponent /> that has to handle this special case

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something similiar and pretty simple.

```changeScroll(){
    let style = document.body.style.overflow 
    document.body.style.overflow = (style === 'hidden') ? 'auto':'hidden'
}```

```<div 
onMouseEnter={this.changeScroll}
onMouseLeave={this.changeScroll}
/>
    <ReactComponent/>
</div>```

Answer (score 13):

Thanks! I was looking for a current answer for managing it.

My ReactJS solution was to add and remove the event when onMouseEnter/Leave is detected. Additionally, with the use of `passive`, taken from this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503230/how-to-turn-off-passive-event-listener-for-mouse-wheel-scroll).

**Principal component:**

```
<Wrapper
    onWheel={this.handleScroll}
    onMouseEnter={this.disableScroll}
    onMouseLeave={this.enableScroll}
> ...</Wrapper>
```

**handleScroll():**

```
public handleScroll = (event) => {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      this.decreaseValue()
    } else {
      this.increaseValue()
    }
}
```

**enableScroll():**

```
public enableScroll = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('wheel', this.preventDefault, false)
}
```

**disableScroll():**

```
public disableScroll = () => {
    document.addEventListener('wheel', this.preventDefault, {
      passive: false,
    })
}
```

**preventdefault():**

```
public preventDefault(e: any) {
    e = e || window.event
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
    e.returnValue = false
  }
```

Comment: I tried several solutions. This was which better worked! Can implement in you code too and be happy! =)

Comment: How does `decreaseValue` and `increaseValue` look?

Comment: @Ini It depends on your use case, it's just for handling each scroll up and down internally.

Comment: You would scroll manually there via setting a new value to `scrollLeft` for example right?

Comment: @Ini Indeed, you could use `scrollLeft`,`scrollTop`, or `scrollTo` or any other method.

Comment: It would be nice if there would be some css similar to touch-action, but for wheel instead of touch... maybe wheel-action or so, because this would greatly simplify things :/